# Minimal reproducable example to check if some class or some node is present in component? Not snapshot tetsing

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, testcase

Hi I have a component tripDetails and its associate test file

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJSON from 'enzyme-to-json';
import tripDetails from './index';

const defaultProps = [
  {
    tripLinkText: 'Book an airport transfer'
  }
 {
    tripLinkText: 'Book an Hotel transfer'
  }
]

describe('trip card section', () => {
  it('testing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<tripDetails {...defaultProps} />);
    expect(toJSON(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But i need to check if some element is present. I dont want snapshot testing,other than that what all i can test? if so how i will write the same

Also tried with this

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { render } from 'enzyme';

import Foo from './Foo';

describe('<Foo />', () => {
  it('renders three `.foo-bar`s', () => {
    const wrapper = render(<Foo />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.foo-bar')).to.have.lengthOf(3);
  });
```

But its giving error     MobX injector: Store 'context' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

Comment: Have you read [the Enzyme docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/)?

Comment: Yes,but i am unable to replicate the same
```  it('renders children when passed in', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow((
      <MyComponent>
        <div className="unique" />
      </MyComponent>
    ));
    expect(wrapper.contains(<div className="unique" />)).to.equal(true);
  });```

Comment: So [edit] the question to give a [mcve] of that attempt, illustrating the specific problem and including the output. Also take a look at what *is* getting rendered (with e.g. `wrapper.debug`) - maybe the test *should* fail? If you don't want a snapshot test, showing us a snapshot test is no help at all.

Comment: No, **you** need to provide the example. This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: getting this error :    MobX injector: Store 'context' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

Comment: Then **[edit] the question** to show that. You haven't even *mentioned* MobX up to now - evidently you're trying to test a *connected* component that requires a context to be provided, so you need to either provide that context in the test or refactor the component to decouple it from MobX and test the unconnected version.

Comment: No, thank you. I suggest you do some research around that error message.

Answer (score 1):

1.To find an element in the rendered compoment you need to use `find` operator on you wrapper. 
2. Use shallow to render your component.

```
let wrapper  = shallow(<Component />);
const element = wrapper.find('.yourClass');
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: The component isn't getting as far as rendering, and the OP already knows how to use `.find`.